# How can I access a (disk1 support) subdirectory?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

I'm currently trying to design an install package for a web based application. It requires a custom instance of sql server that needs to be user defined. I currently have an .ini file that's used while executing an sql installation.

I have copied the sql installation folder to the DISK1 section of the support files of the Installshield IDE and can't seem to access any files within that folder in order to dynamically modify the .ini to trigger a custom sql installation.

How do I correctly reference a subdirectory of the DISK1 support files? Following some research on this I have tried numerous variations such as `LaunchAppAndWait(SRCDIR ^ "\sqlserver\install.bat", "", WAIT)` yet have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is interested the solution to my question after some trial and error was `(LaunchAppAndWait(PACKAGE_LOCATION ^ "sqlserver/install.bat", "", WAIT) < 0)`